# Admob payment: Wire transfer to bank account

Tags: admob, transfer, bank, fee

I have earned 169.99 in Sep, 2022. Admob sent an email regarding my payments. In the end, I received $31 less than I earned. Can somebody tell me if $31 is a wire transfer fee or something else? Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can request a receipt from the bank

Comment: I got the receipt, but there were only a few charges. While transferring payment by WU, I almost always get the same amount as written on the admob payment receipt. Somebody knows the wire transfer charges?

Comment: After search on google, I got 
"Wire transfer fees typically range from $0 to $50. Domestic outgoing wire transfer fees typically range from $0 to $35, while international outgoing wire transfer fees are usually $35-50."